# How to zgrep an UPPERCASE as a lowercase without pipes / variables / echo

Tags: shell, grep, pattern-matching, zgrep

How to zgrep an UPPERCASE PATTERN as it was a lowercase, e.x.:

```
zgrep 'MYPATTERN' *.gz
```

matching: mypattern

**Without**: pipes, echoes, files or variables. E.x.:

```
s="Hello World!" 
echo $s  # Hello World!
a=${s,,}
zgrep "$a" *.gz
```

**NOR**

```
echo 'MYPATTERN' | sed -e 's/.*/\L&/g'  #this line not tested
```

**NOR**

```
zgrep -i 'MYPATTERN' *.gz #option -i is to heavy
```

The goal is to search for a plain simple hexa string in log files, but they are always given as UPPERCASE, but logged as lowercase.

The harvesting is made in a shared remove server where writing a function wouldn't be the nicest. I'm searching for a clean solution. That's the reason why I'm avoiding pipes and variables.

subcommands are welcome "``" but without pipes or many commands inside it.

Comment: @anubhava no, it is copied and pasted. Or pasted through the middle mouse button.

Comment: Combining small, specialized tools that each does one thing well is "the UNIX way". Asking for one tool that does everything you want out-of-the-box without configuration, options or pre-or-post-processing is... unreasonable, unless you want that tool to be a general-purpose programming language interpreter (and its arguments to contain code).

Comment: (It's not at all clear what you mean by "writing a function wouldn't be the nicest". If what you don't know how to do is conveniently pass a function over ssh to run on a remote system, for instance, that's a question already separately asked and answered on this site, so if you were making it clear *why* you thought a function wouldn't work, we could potentially provide an answer that spoke directly to that immediate issue).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy all your argumentation makes no sense. Ok, Linux is a GNU Linux system with lots of binaries that helps get where you want. But that DOESN'T MEAN that your should use 10 commands instead of 2. My needs was far clear on this one.

Comment: I certainly **don't** understand that claimed need. If the 10 commands are internal to the interpreter, but the 2 are both external -- requiring `mkfifo()`, `fork()`, `exeve()`, `wait()`, etc -- then the 10 will be far faster to execute in the relevant cases. And in the case of `-i`, you're not adding any external commands at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a crazy set of restrictions. How about

```
zgrep "$(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<<"MYPATTERN")" *.gz
```

How is `zgrep -i` "too heavy"?

Comment: search for a fix pattern is lighter than any combination.

Comment: Didn't know about "<<<", with your answer I did: `sed 's/.*/\L&/g' <<< MYPATTERN` that is lean and perfectly fits to my needs.

`zgrep \`sed 's/.*/\L&/g' <<< MYPATTERN\` *.gz`

Comment: If you're looking for lighter, add the `-F` option

Comment: @RodrigoGurgel, it's not quite so lean once you know how it works -- it creates a temporary file, writes contents to that temporary file, redirects from the file as stdin, and deletes it. Much more efficient to use a variable with a parameter expansion, even though that's something you say you explicitly don't want.

Comment: @RodrigoGurgel, "better" meaning more efficient? Absolutely. "Better" meaning it complies with your arbitrary constraints? That's not a game I have any interest in playing.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you but having a pipe

```
grep -o "string" yourfile | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]
```

Comment: Doing `tr` *after* the search means you get very different results than you would if you'd done it beforehand.